# Abstract click listener Android Button

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener

I have a Vector with 14 buttons with the same click's functionality.
How can i do to abstract the method?

I did this but doesn't works.

```
for(Button b: botonesAEncender)
            b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    textoRespuesta.append(b.getText());
                    b.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    tap.start();
                    verificarVictoria();
                    botonesUsados.add(b);
                }
            });
```

on b said the error said: "Variable is accessed within inner class. Needs to be declared final"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declared that variable as final ;

```
for(final Button b: botonesAEncender)
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                textoRespuesta.append(b.getText());
                b.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                tap.start();
                verificarVictoria();
                botonesUsados.add(b);
            }
        });
```

Comment: it compile but procede nullPointerException